# Child component with empty path is not being loaded

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

[I am loading homepage component from the app component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx80q.png)

In the homepage component, I am using lazy loading to load the body component(with empty path). However, the body component is never loaded.[Router module of homepage component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKNSn.png)[Router module of body component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXA9X.png)

I have another project where I did the same thing and it worked. What did I do wrong?

I used a path and router link for the body component and it worked. But I still want to use lazy loading so I'm trying to figure out why is it not working

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. [ask]